# Amend node item where item is greater than or less than an integer?

Tags: xml, batch-file, xslt, cmd, vbscript

**I need to output/amend item(s) in an XML where an item**

1. `<TrackNumber>` matches number 2 onwards (to infinity) integer value
2. read from XML is greater than, less than, less than or equal to a    specified integer value

**Criteria: For items matching TrackNumber 2 onwards (to infinity):**

```
FOR <ScannedTrack>
WHERE <TrackNumber>2 (and onwards)
IF <Codec>2048</Codec>
AND <Bitrate> is <= LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO <Bitrate>192000</Bitrate>

OUTPUT/WRITE <Encoder> item as:
<Encoder>Ac3Passthrough</Encoder>
AND DELETE element/node <MixDown>


FOR <ScannedTrack>
<TrackNumber>2 (and onwards)
IF <Codec>2048</Codec> or <Codec>16777216</Codec> or <Codec>262144</Codec> or <Codec>8192</Codec> or <Codec>4444</Codec>
AND <Bitrate> is > GREATER THAN <Bitrate>192000</Bitrate>

OUTPUT/WRITE the following to each specific item:
<AudioTrack>
<MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
<Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
<Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
```

**NOTE:** The elements `<MixDown>, <Encoder> and <Bitrate>` contain existing values already, so replace/overwrite these with the output/write values shown above if match conditions.

Can someone please help me with scripting - VBScript, XSLT or Batch with Regex to help achieve the required output?

**I have tried to have a go with the XSL stylesheet code below, but I think some of my syntax is incorrect, could use some help:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

        <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

        <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber = (>= '2')]">
            <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack[Codec = (2048)] and [Bitrate (<=192000)]/Encoder">
                <xsl:copy>Ac3Passthrough</xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>


            <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber = (>= '2')]">
                <xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack[Codec = (2048, 262144, 8192, 4444, 16777216)] and [Bitrate = (>192000)]/MixDown/Encoder/Bitrate">
                    <xsl:copy>Stereo</xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy>Ac3</xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy>192</xsl:copy>
                </xsl:template>

            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the example XML file to test with:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfQueueTask xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <QueueTask>
        <Task>
            <AudioTracks>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>5point1</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>EAc3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>448</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>1</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (E-AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>16777216</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>448000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>5point1</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>2</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>2048</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>192000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>EAc3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>224</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>3</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (E-AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>16777216</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>224000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>5point1</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>128</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>4</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>2048</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>224000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>5point1</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>ffaac</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>256</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>5</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (DTS-HD MA) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>262144</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>1536000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Lame</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>256</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>6</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (DTS) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>8192</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>1536000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>ffaac</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>160</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>7</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>TrueHD 5.1</Description>
                        <Codec>4444</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>1536000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
            </AudioTracks>
        </Task>
    </QueueTask>
</ArrayOfQueueTask>
```

**And here is the expected output XML after transformations applied:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfQueueTask xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <QueueTask>
        <Task>
            <AudioTracks>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>5point1</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>EAc3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>448</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>1</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (E-AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>16777216</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>448000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <Encoder>Ac3Passthrough</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>2</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>2048</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>192000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>3</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (E-AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>16777216</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>224000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>4</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>2048</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>224000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>5</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (DTS-HD MA) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>262144</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>1536000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>6</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>English (DTS) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>8192</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>1536000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>7</TrackNumber>
                        <Description>TrueHD 5.1</Description>
                        <Codec>4444</Codec>
                        <Bitrate>1536000</Bitrate>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
            </AudioTracks>
        </Task>
    </QueueTask>
</ArrayOfQueueTask>
```

**Order of Original XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfQueueTask xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <QueueTask>
        <Task>
            <AudioTracks>
                <AudioTrack>
                    <IsNotifying>true</IsNotifying>
                    <DRC>0</DRC>
                    <Gain>0</Gain>
                    <MixDown>5point1</MixDown>
                    <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
                    <SampleRate>0</SampleRate>
                    <EncoderRateType>Bitrate</EncoderRateType>
                    <Bitrate>448</Bitrate>
                    <Quality>-1</Quality>
                    <TrackName/>
                    <IsDefault>false</IsDefault>
                    <SampleRateDisplayValue>Auto</SampleRateDisplayValue>
                    <ScannedTrack>
                        <TrackNumber>1</TrackNumber>
                        <Language>English</Language>
                        <LanguageCode>eng</LanguageCode>
                        <Description>English (E-AC3) (5.1 ch)</Description>
                        <Codec>16777216</Codec>
                        <SampleRate>48000</SampleRate>
                        <Bitrate>224000</Bitrate>
                        <ChannelLayout>128000</ChannelLayout>
                    </ScannedTrack>
                </AudioTrack>
            </AudioTracks>
        </Task>
    </QueueTask>
</ArrayOfQueueTask>
```

Comment: The stylesheet you have added is tagged as `version="2.0"` but it requires XSLT 3.0 (or rather would require XSLT 3.0, if it's syntax were valid). If (as you say below) you're using `libxslt` then you need an XSLT 1.0 solution. -- P.S. The question would be easier to understand if you would minimize the input XML and  show the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I thought I had read libxslt could support 2.0. If not, what is the next most portable command line that can support 2.0 ?

Comment: `libxslt` is an XSLT 1.0 processor - you can verify this as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25244370/how-can-i-check-which-xslt-processor-is-being-used-in-solr/25245033#25245033.  -- Still no expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Simplified the Example XML and added the expected XML output. I guess I need an XSLT 1.0 solution as you have suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very difficult and time-consuming to follow. AFAICT, you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 1 and ScannedTrack/Codec = 2048 and ScannedTrack/Bitrate &lt;= 192000]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Encoder>Ac3Passthrough</Encoder>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::MixDown or self::Encoder)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 1 and (ScannedTrack/Codec = 2048 or ScannedTrack/Codec = 262144 or ScannedTrack/Codec = 8192 or ScannedTrack/Codec = 4444) and ScannedTrack/Bitrate > 192000]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
        <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
        <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::MixDown or self::Encoder or self::Bitrate)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

***Added in response to your comment:***

If you want to preserve the original order of the elements under `AudioTrack`, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 1 and ScannedTrack/Codec = 2048 and ScannedTrack/Bitrate &lt;= 192000]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="IsNotifying | DRC | Gain"/>        
        <Encoder>Ac3Passthrough</Encoder>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SampleRate | EncoderRateType | Bitrate | Quality | TrackName | IsDefault | SampleRateDisplayValue | ScannedTrack"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AudioTrack[ScannedTrack/TrackNumber > 1 and (ScannedTrack/Codec = 2048 or ScannedTrack/Codec = 262144 or ScannedTrack/Codec = 8192 or ScannedTrack/Codec = 4444) and ScannedTrack/Bitrate > 192000]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="IsNotifying | DRC | Gain"/>        
        <MixDown>stereo</MixDown>
        <Encoder>Ac3</Encoder>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SampleRate | EncoderRateType"/>  
        <Bitrate>192</Bitrate>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Quality | TrackName | IsDefault | SampleRateDisplayValue | ScannedTrack"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is assuming the original order is:

- IsNotifying
- DRC
- Gain
- MixDown
- Encoder
- SampleRate
- EncoderRateType
- Bitrate
- Quality
- TrackName
- IsDefault
- SampleRateDisplayValue
- ScannedTrack

Comment: It is almost there... just one small problem. When you asked to me minimize the XML, I removed some elements not relevant to the question, but these elements are still required in the final XML output. When I run the XSLT stylesheet, the elements that were modified using the stylesheet now appear above all other elements on the newly created XML. I have included an example of the correct layout above. The order under <AudioTrack> should be <IsNotifying> <DRC> <Gain> <MixDown> <Encoder> <SampleRate> <EncoderRateType> <Bitrate> <Quality> <TrackName> <IsDefault> <SampleRateDisplayValue>

Comment: However when I run the code as it is right now, <MixDown> <Encoder> <Bitrate> always appear at the top, above all other elements under <AudioTrack>. Can this be fixed so that all the elements (just like in the "Order of Original XML File" shown above) appear in their correct order?

Comment: Is the order really important?

Comment: I thought it should not, but it seems to matter. I feed this back into another piece of proprietary software and if items are not in the expected order on the XML it appears they are ignored.